# Delphi 7 Glyph.Data Hex to Data URI

Tags: c#, html, delphi, delphi-7

I'm trying to convert a Delphi-7 ui to a webinterface. Delphi stores button icons in the property Glyph.Data as a hexadecimal string. For example:

```
object Btn1: TSpeedButton
        Left = -1
        Top = -1
        Width = 26
        Height = 27
        Anchors = [akTop, akRight]
        Flat = True
        Glyph.Data = {
          36060000424D3606000000000000360000002800000020000000100000000100
          1800000000000006000000000000000000000000000000000000BECACDBECACD
          BECACDBECACDBECACDBECACDD9D3E6BAB4E3E8E2E8BECACD9A96DE0000CC0000
          CC5E5BD6BECACDBECACDBECACDBECACDBECACDBECACDBECACDBECACDBECACD8D
          A2A7BECACDBECACDBECACD8C8C8C8C8C8C8DA2A7BECACDBECACDBECACDBECACD
          BECACDBECACDBECACDD9D3E6100FCD0000CC100FCDE8E2E93E3DD20000CC0000
          CC0000CCBECACDBECACDBECACDBECACDBECACDBECACDBECACDBECACD64646464
          6464646464BECACD8C8C8C646464646464646464BECACDBECACDBECACDBECACD
          BECACDBECACDBECACDBAB4E40000CC0000CC0000CCBAB4E44E4CD60000CC0000
          CC100FCDBECACDBECACDBECACDBECACDBECACDBECACDBECACDBECACD64646464
          64646464648DA2A78C8C8C646464646464646464BECACDBECACDBECACDBECACD
          BECACDBAB4E4D9D3E6E8E2E91F1ECF0000CC2F2ED0BECACDC9C3E54E4CD63E3D
          D2AAA5E0BECACDBECACDBECACDBECACDBECACD8DA2A78DA2A7BECACD64646464
          6464646464BECACDBECACD8C8C8C8C8C8C8DA2A7BECACDBECACDBECACDBECACD
          6D6AD90000CC0000CCBAB4E4BECACDC9C3E5BECACDBECACDBECACDBECACDBECA
          CDBECACDBECACDBECACDBECACDBECACD8DA2A76464646464648DA2A7BECACDBE
          CACDBECACDBECACDBECACDBECACDBECACDBECACDBECACDBECACDBECACDBECACD
          3E3DD20000CC0000CC7B78DBBECACDBECACDBECACDBECACDBECACDBECACDBECA
          CDBECACDBECACDBECACDBECACDBECACD8C8C8C6464646464648DA2A7BECACDBE
          CACDBECACDBECACDBECACDBECACDBECACDBECACDBECACDBECACDBECACDBECACD
          AAA5E01F1ECF3E3DD2D9D3E6BECACDBECACDBECACDBECACDBECACDBECACDBECA
          CDBECACDBECACDBECACDBECACDBECACD8DA2A7646464646464BECACDBECACDBE
          CACDBECACDBECACDBECACDBECACDBECACDBECACDBECACDBECACDBECACDBECACD
          BECACDBECACDBECACDBECACDBECACDBECACDBECACDBECACDBECACDBECACDBECA
          CDBECACDBECACDBECACDBECACDBECACDBECACDBECACDBECACDBECACDBECACDBE
          CACDBECACDBECACDBECACDBECACDBECACDBECACDBECACDBECACDBECACDBECACD
          2F2ED00000CC8B87DDBECACDBECACDBECACDBECACDBECACDBECACDBECACDBECA
          CDBECACDBECACDBECACDBECACDBECACD646464646464646464BECACDBECACDBE
          CACDBECACDBECACDBECACDBECACDBECACDBECACDBECACDBECACDBECACDBECACD
          0000CC0000CC3E3DD2BECACDBECACDBECACDBECACDBECACDBECACDBECACDBECA
          CDBECACDBECACDBECACDBECACDBECACD646464646464646464BECACDBECACDBE
          CACDBECACDBECACDBECACDBECACDBECACDBECACDBECACDBECACDBECACDBECACD
          6D6AD93E3DD2AAA5E0BECACDBECACDBECACDBECACDBECACDBECACDBECACDBECA
          CDBECACDBECACDBECACDBECACDBECACD8C8C8C6464648DA2A7BECACDBECACDBE
          CACDBECACDBECACDBECACDBECACDBECACDBECACDBECACDBECACDBECACDBECACD
          BECACDBECACDBECACDBAB4E4BECACDBECACDBECACDBECACDBECACDBECACDBECA
          CDBECACDBECACDBECACDBECACDBECACDBECACDBECACDBECACD8C8C8CBECACDBE
          CACDBECACDBECACDBECACDBECACDBECACDBECACDBECACDBECACDBECACDBECACD
          BECACDBECACD4E4CD60000CC7B78DBBECACDBECACDBECACDBECACDBECACDBECA
          CDBECACDBECACDBECACDBECACDBECACDBECACDBECACD6464646464648C8C8CBE
          CACDBECACDBECACDBECACDBECACDBECACDBECACDBECACDBECACDBECACDBECACD
          BECACDBECACD4E4CD60000CC7B78DBE8E2E98B87DDC9C3E5BECACDBECACDBECA
          CDBECACDBECACDBECACDBECACDBECACDBECACDBECACD6464646464648C8C8CBE
          CACD6464648DA2A7BECACDBECACDBECACDBECACDBECACDBECACDBECACDBECACD
          BECACDBECACDE8E2E9BAB4E4BECACD8B87DD0000CC3E3DD2BECACD7B78DB4E4C
          D6BECACDBECACDBECACDBECACDBECACDBECACDBECACDBECACD8DA2A7BECACD64
          6464646464646464BECACD6464646464648C8C8CBECACDBECACDBECACDBECACD
          BECACDBECACDBECACDBECACDBECACDD9D3E63E3DD29A96DEBECACD4E4CD60000
          CCD9D3E6BECACDBECACDBECACDBECACDBECACDBECACDBECACDBECACDBECACDBE
          CACD6464648C8C8CBECACD6464646464648C8C8CBECACDBECACD}
        NumGlyphs = 2
```

How do I convert this string into a Data URI for HTML? I tried to convert it into a byte array to make a bitmap out of it, but this also fails. I wrote a small C# Helper tool to do the conversation, but I can't get it to run. It throws out an ArgumentException on Image.FromStream(ms).

```
    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        byte[] bytes = StringToByteArray(textBox1.Text);
        byte[] newBytes = new byte[bytes.Length - 4];
        for(var i = 4; i < bytes.Length; i++)
        {
            newBytes[i - 4] = bytes[i];
        }
        using (var ms = new MemoryStream(bytes))
        {
            Image image = Image.FromStream(ms);
            pictureBox_originalImage.Image = image;
        }
    }
    public static byte[] StringToByteArray(String hex)
    {
        int NumberChars = hex.Length;
        byte[] bytes = new byte[NumberChars / 2];
        for (int i = 0; i < NumberChars; i += 2)
            bytes[i / 2] = Convert.ToByte(hex.Substring(i, 2), 16);
        return bytes;
    }
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: `using (var ms = new MemoryStream(bytes))` should refer to `newBytes`, no?

Comment: Yes, @TomBrunberg is correct. This is the sort of thing that would easily be noticed were you to do some basic debugging. It seems to me from all my experience here on SO that basic debugging skills are very sorely lacking in modern day developers. And I don't mean the practical skill of using an IDE debugger. I mean the higher level skill of knowing what information to inspect to be able to diagnose where the fault it.

Comment: yeah, I get that. I did use newBytes, but before I posted this I also wanted to see what would happen if I use bytes instead, and just forgot to switch it out again before I post it. It's not my profession to develop code.

Comment: Assuming @boimel solved their problem already.

One thing to note is the `NumGlyphs = 2` at  the very bottom of the object
When extracting the BMP, it turns out it is actually 2 images side by side

`file Btn1.bmp
Btn1.bmp: PC bitmap, Windows 3.x format, 32 x 16 x 24, image size 1536, cbSize 1590, bits offset 54`

This would probably also be visible if the Glyph was saved from the Delphi IDE
Perhaps the question would have had more success if it was broken into several parts,
* how to extract the image from the dfm
* and a separate one on how to convert the standard bmp into the uri

Answer (score 4):

Perform the following to extract a Windows bitmap from this Delphi form file:

1. Read the hex string.
2. Convert the hex string to binary (a byte array). If using Delphi you can do this with `HexToBin` from the `Classes` unit. If using some other language then you will have to use the appropriate function to convert from hex to binary.
3. Remove the first 4 bytes from the byte array. These bytes that are removed contain the length of the remaining bytes.
4. Save these bytes to a file.

What you have saved is a Windows bitmap file. You'll likely want to convert to a web friendly format such as PNG, but I presume you already have tools to do that.

Finally, you'll need to encode that PNG file as base64 and thus form a data URI. Again, I am presuming that you know how to do that.

In the example you present you can also see the `NumGlyphs` property indicates that the glyph contains two images. You might want to split the extracted bitmap into multiple images.

Comment: Thanks, I tried removing the first 4 bytes, but I guess what I try to save is not a valid image. I posted the code in my question.

Comment: Do some debugging. Look at the output file in a hex editor. Is it what you expect.

Answer (score 0):

Excuse me in advance for my very bad english.

There are two options.

1) working with a file text without blank spaces
   use a algorithm/function that use readln.
   I post this approch below

2) I have realized some functions that work perfectly

function HexaBmp(const aSource, aDest: String): Integer;  // done
function BmpHexa(const aSource, aDest: String): Integer;  // work done
function Bin2Bin(const aSource, aDest: String): Integer;  // work done (binary in binary text)
function Txt2Bin(const aSource, aDest: String): Integer;  // (binary text in binary) working in progress...

This functions uses this subfunctions...

procedure Reading;
begin
  BlockRead(F1, PFBuf^, SIZEFB, BytesIng)
end;

procedure Writing;
begin
  BlockWrite(F2, BLWR, Z, BytesOut)
end;

but for copyright reasons don't post this (i dont'understend if i'll be owner of these)
Sorry for this... I can't explain more. It's more plus complicated.
a sofisticate and robust algorithm is necessary but is very fast.

But don't worry because you can use this my little program below for the scope that use the first approach.

```
program HexaToBmp;

{$APPTYPE CONSOLE}

uses
  SysUtils, Windows;

const
  CHX: array ['0'..'F'] of Byte = (0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15);

var
  FtoW: TextFile;
  FtoR: TextFile;
  WFile: String;     // name of write file
  Buff: String;      // string buffer of read file
  vS: String;        // calc string
  FNY: Word;         // final Y
  M: Word;           // prior of Y
  Y: Word;           // in loop while read index

  procedure TextSeek(var aFtx: Text; POS: Cardinal);
  begin
    with TTextRec(aFtx) do
    begin
      BufPos:= 0;
      BufEnd:= 0;
      SetFilePointer(Handle, POS, nil, FILE_BEGIN)
    end
  end;

begin
  WFile:= StringReplace(ParamStr(1), ExtractFileExt(ParamStr(1)), 'WF', []) + '.bmp';
  AssignFile(FtoR, ParamStr(1));
  AssignFile(FtoW, WFile);
  vS:= '';

  try
    Reset(FtoR);
    ReWrite(FtoW);
    TextSeek(FtoR, 8);            // position after the first 8 byte

    while not EOF(FtoR) do
    begin
      Readln(FtoR, Buff);
      FNY:= Length(Buff) + 1;
      M:= 1;
      Y:= 2;

      while Y < FNY do
      begin
        if Buff[Y] = #$A then   // new line jump
        begin
          Write(FtoW, vS);      // writing current line
          vS:= '';
          Y:= Y + 1             // jump correct index
        end
        else
          vS:= vS + Chr(16 * CHX[Buff[M]] + CHX[Buff[Y]]);   // calc bin value

        M:= Y + 1;             // increment the variable values
        Y:= M + 1
      end
    end;

    Write(FtoW, vS)
  finally
    CloseFile(FtoR);
    CloseFile(FtoW)
  end

end.
`
```